# [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsuserdefaults, unrecognized-selector

I am creating one app in which I am saving my array of custom object in NSUserDefaults using this below code :

```
[Util setSubProductsArrayPreference:myArray forKey:productId];
```

//Util.m

```
+(void)setSubProductsArrayPreference:(NSMutableArray *)subProducts forKey:(NSString *)string
{
    for (int i=0; i<subProducts.count; i++) {
        SubProducts *po=[subProducts objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *st=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [Util setSubProductsPreference:po forKey:st];

    }
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:subProducts];
    [prefs setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:string];
    [prefs synchronize];
}


+(void)setSubProductsPreference:(SubProducts *)subProducts forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:subProducts]; 
    [prefs setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:key];//here it is crashing
    [prefs synchronize];
}
```

This code is working fine with iOS7 and prior..The problem is when I am running my same code with iOS8 in xCode6 then I am getting the below error :

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000f23

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000f23'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042fbf35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103bbabb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010430304d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010425b27c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010425ae18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042bc790 _CFPrefsEncodeKeyValuePairIntoMessage + 64
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042fe286 -[CFPrefsPlistSource sendMessageSettingValue:forKey:] + 102
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010423cef7 -[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_setValue:forKey:] + 215
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010423cdee -[CFPrefsSource setValue:forKey:] + 62
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001041fa1f8 +[CFPrefsSource withSourceForIdentifier:user:byHost:container:perform:] + 1112
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010423cd63 _CFPreferencesSetValueWithContainer + 227
    11  Foundation                          0x000000010374099b -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 46
    12  HP ProTrain                         0x0000000101186787 +[Util setSubProductsArrayPreference:forKey:] + 487
    13  HP ProTrain                         0x0000000101115a38 __74-[DesktopProductsViewController fetchingProductSubCategoryDataFromServer:]_block_invoke_2 + 3096
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001051b4ba6 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001051d27f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001051bb8fb _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 949
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104263fe9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104226eeb __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104226486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001082c29f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000102463420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    22  HP ProTrain                         0x00000001010c1a87 main + 151
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000105207145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Do any one else experience the same problem?

Comment: There is a mismatch between your indiction where it is crashing and the stacktrace: the stacktrace says it crashes inside `setSubProductsArrayPreference` while you state it crashes inside `setSubProductsPreference`

Comment: why downvote, what is wrong in my question?

Comment: 1) Symbolicate the crash log. 2) Once you have the line number info from step 1, point out the exact line of code causing the crash. 3) Debug the app and see why you are getting an `NSNumber` object where you expected an `NSString` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
 [Util setSubProductsArrayPreference:myArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",productId]];
```

Comment: This is not the proper solution. You say the code worked in iOS 7 but not iOS 8. The proper solution is to fix the cause of the problem. This solution simply hides the problem by converting the unexpected `NSNumber` object into an `NSString`. Fix the problem instead of applying a band-aid that hides it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, your `productId` is not returning string. Just typecast `productId` to NSString before `setObject.`

Comment: If `productId` is an `NSNumber` then casting it to `NSString` does not solve the problem at all. The same error will happen.

Comment: I think the user has already accepted the answer,it really solved the issue,which causing the error according to the code.We have just pointed out "productId" is causing the error,the OP is smart enough to solve the later part.

Comment: "NSNumber to an NSString", it wrong it should be  " to a NSString" . Anways It did solved the issue cause NSNumber was causing the crash , The OP has no idea where the crash was causing, that is why others users pointed out that. So the comment has nothing to do with the answer.